# How to convert unicode in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API. Please see this [JSON response](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Aalborg&destination=Copenhagen&sensor=false).

The HTML instructions is written like this:

```
"html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eEnggårdsgade\u003c/b\u003e"
```

How can I convert the unicodes `\u003c`, `\u003e` etc. in JavaScript?

Comment: `\u003cb` actually represents two characters in JavaScript: `\u003c` is [a Unicode escape sequence](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode) for `<`; the second character is `b`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are [Unicode character escape sequences](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode) in a JavaScript string. As far as JavaScript is concerned, they are the same character.

```
'\u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e' == '<b>left</b>'; // true
```

So, you don’t need to do any conversion at all.

Comment: I would like to add the string to a div using JavaScript, so I need the `<b>` instead of `\u003cb\u003e`.

Comment: @DennisMadsen As I just told you, they’re exactly the same string! Try it: `document.body.innerHTML = '\u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e';` will have the exact same effect as `document.body.innerHTML = '<b>left</b>';`.

Answer (score 7):

Below is a simpler way thanks to modern JS .

ES6 / ES2015 introduced the normalize() method on the String prototype, so we can do:

```
var directions = "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eEnggårdsgade\u003c/b\u003e";

directions.normalize();

//it will return : "Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Enggårdsgade</b>"
```

Refer to this article : https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-unicode/

Comment: best answer after long search

Comment: awesome! It saves my life

Comment: This answer is nonsense.  Just open your browser console and paste in:

"Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eEnggårdsgade\u003c/b\u003e"

And it will return:

'Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Enggårdsgade</b>'

Answer (score 5):

you can use [JSON.parse](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) directly on JSON response then the unicode characters will automatically converted to its html counter parts (\u003c will be converted to < sign in html)

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({a : 'Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eEnggårdsgade\u003c/b\u003e'}));
```

Comment: JavaScript strings do not consist of HTML entities, what do you mean?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i was trying to say that \u003c will be converted to < sign in html

Comment: No, no conversion! Nothing to do with HTML! See Mathias' answer. One could even think it would converted to &lt; in *HTML* .-)

Answer (score -1):

This small function may help

```
String.prototype.toUnicode = function(){
    var hex, i;
    var result = "";
    for (i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
        hex = this.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
        result += ("\\u00"+hex).slice(-7);
    }

    return result;
};
```