# How do i parse and format Google Directions JSON?

Tags: android, json, string, parsing, formatting

I am trying to parse the "html_instructions" string from the "steps" array at [this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=33.7489,-84.3881&destination=33.7514,-84.7478&sensor=false) link:

I have no trouble parsing the string, but it returns with bits of code mixed in.  For Example, the parsed string of:

```
"html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003esouthwest\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eCapitol Square SW\u003c/b\u003e",
```

Appears as:

```
Head<br>southwest"</br>"towards<br>...
```

Instead of appearing simply as:

```
Head southwest towards...
```

Is there a way i can format the string to remove the "breaks"?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a **regex** to remove `HTML` tags from your content.

```
  String htmlString = "Head<br>southwest</br>towards<br>...";
  String noHtml = htmlString.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into answer for this question.

[How to convert unicode in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932895/how-to-convert-unicode-in-javascript)

Basically the response is in Unicode, hence the < is represented by \u003c & > by \u003e you can use String manipulation to replace these strings with appropriate charterers.

Try doing something like this

```
String parseResponse = response.replaceAll("\u003c","<");
```

This will get your string in the proper html format.

Comment: if you need to replace the html breaks you can just use the string replace method instead of replacing < you can replace it with a blank char.