# Regex struct in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I am getting data returned in a JSON file with Unicode characters. How to replace Unicode characters as per my example?

```
\u003cli class=\"channels-content-item\"\u003e\n
  \n
\u003cdiv class=\"shmoovie-content-cell\"\u003e\n
\u003ca href=\"\/movie\/the-makeover\" class=\"ux-thumb-wrap contains-addto  yt-uix-sessionlink\" data-sessionlink=\"ei=Oo21UdLqM8aDhgHc_IHYCA\"\u003e
```

After replacing with regex:

`\u003c` must be replaced by `<`

`\u003e` must be replaced by `>`

`\/` must be replaced by `/`

`\"` must be replaced by `"`

How to do that?

Comment: Check out this question and its accepted answer: [How to convert unicode in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932895/how-to-convert-unicode-in-javascript). You probably don't need to convert anything, since using the string value as html will render the expected results.

Comment: I don't know but i tried many ways. My problem is load this link http://www.youtube.com/c4_browse_ajax?action_load_more_videos=1&channel_id=SBae7jiISxYlc&live_view=500&paging=1&flow=grid&view=11&fluid=True and get thumbnails, name, id of movies. Can u tell me one way to to that with javascript. Sorry because i'm a newbie and i am working with ios.

Answer (score 1):

Using the bit of the string you posted I put this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DPUjb/1/) together that shows how to just use the string value you have (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932895/how-to-convert-unicode-in-javascript) SO answer I mentioned in the comments).

HTML

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

JS

```
var s = "\u003cli class=\"channels-content-item\"\u003e\n\n\u003cdiv class=\"shmoovie-content-cell\"\u003e\n\u003ca href=\"\/movie\/the-makeover\" class=\"ux-thumb-wrap contains-addto  yt-uix-sessionlink\" data-sessionlink=\"ei=Oo21UdLqM8aDhgHc_IHYCA\"\u003e";

var div = document.getElementById('content');
div.innerHTML = s;
console.log(s);
```

Which sets the HTML content for the `div` with the elements:

```
<li class="channels-content-item">

<div class="shmoovie-content-cell">
<a href="/movie/the-makeover" class="ux-thumb-wrap contains-addto yt-uix-sessionlink" data-sessionlink="ei=Oo21UdLqM8aDhgHc_IHYCA">
```

Although it's not valid HTML, javascript seems to figure it out, at least it does in Chrome.

Comment: Sorry man! I can't do follow what you said. Because i'm coding with ios. I tried this code  :   var r = /\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi;
    content = content.replace(r, function (match, grp) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16)); } );
    content = unescape(content);  It can replace \u00.. but not enough to replace \/ and \"

Comment: If you are working on iOS but on a web client or page, it's still javascript. I think this comment belongs in another question since I didn't suggest using regexes :P.

Comment: Exaclty i want to parse data of this link http://www.youtube.com/c4_browse_ajax?action_load_more_videos=1&channel_id=SBae7jiISxYlc&live_view=500&paging=1&flow=grid&view=11&fluid=True. To get list movies. I'm a newbie in js :D. So too difficult for me to do that.

Comment: I would suggest to rethink your problem. Parsing HTML from a JSON request is definitely not the best way to get information from YouTube. Consider using the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that regex is the best idea...The below solves the problem using the replace function built into JavaScript.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/5DFUb/1/

```
var str = "\u003cli class=\"channels-content-item\"\u003e\n \n \u003cdiv class=\"shmoovie-content-cell\"\u003e\n \u003ca href=\"/movie/the-makeover\" class=\"ux-thumb-wrap contains-addto yt-uix-sessionlink\" data-sessionlink=\"ei=Oo21UdLqM8aDhgHc_IHYCA\"\u003e";

var newStr = str.replace("\\u003c", "<").replace("\\u003e",">").replace("\\/","/").replace("\\\"","\"");

alert(newStr);
```

Comment: Please try to alert without replace. I think output is same.

Comment: you are correct so does console.log because of what juan.facorro said earlier...if you were to pass this string to something that isn't browser rendered (ie ajax param) it would be what you want.

Comment: I want to do likes this :     var r = /\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi;
    content = content.replace(r, function (match, grp) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16)); } );
    content = unescape(content);

Comment: can't really do that when not everything you are doing is not a character code.